# Google Analytics: what does XX.XX% of total session means?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I opened Google Analytics website->Demographics->Overview and got following data of my android app:
[image]

There is a line at top right corner

```
71.12% of Total sessions
```

What does above line means to the data?

What about the remaining 28.88%?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It means Google was able to identify the age of the visitor during 71.12% of your site visits